# Using unison between two hosts over differents networks

Tags: networking, sync, unison

We want to synchronize a directory, called `docs` between two hosts, called `server` and `laptop`, using `unison`. So we have a `unison` profile `docs.prf` that defines the roots and gives a list of preferred rules for the synchronization. The command `unison` is always run on `laptop`. The problem is that sometimes the synchronization is done through a local network, in this case `server` has an IP like `10.xxx.xxx.xxx` and server is identified as `server.localdomain`, but sometimes it is done over internet, and the IP of `server` is something like `135.xxx.xxx.xxx` and `server` is known as `server.domain.com`.

Of course we want to use the same data `ar...` in both cases and the same rules defined in `docs.prf`, so creating a second profile is not a solution.
I tried to use `unison` command-line options, to change the remote host name (like `-rootalias`, `-host`) , but nothing succeeded. Does anyone have any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way out using a script. It first pings `server.localdomain`. If there is an answer, we are in the private network, default configuration, so it functions as usual. If the ping fails, the script creates a temporary file `/tmp/sshRedirect` containing

```
Host     server.localdomain
HostName server.domain.com
```

and `unison` is called with the options `-sshargs -FsshRedirect` (it's important that there is no space after `F`). This way, unison is transparently redirected.